# Using Regex to update with escape characters for a column value using mysql

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a DB table column named DN whose value is the Distinguished Name of a LDAP user and has the CN value with a comma Ex: '`CN=User,name`,OU=People,DC=domain,DC=com'.

Some of the values could be without commas as well for CN like '`CN=UserName`,OU=People,DC=domain,DC=com'. I would like to add a escape character '\' only for the commas as part of the CN name but not for the Commas which precede OU and DC chars.  I tried to add escape character with the following 3 statements.

```
UPDATE LOGININFO SET DN = REPLACE(DN, ',', '\\,');  

UPDATE LOGININFO SET DN = REPLACE(DN, '\\,OU=', '\,OU=');

UPDATE LOGININFO SET DN = REPLACE(DN, '\\,DC=', '\,DC=');
```

Looking for a single mysql Update statement which would replace 'CN=User,name,OU=People,DC=domain,DC=com' with 'CN=User\,name,OU=People,DC=domain,DC=com'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want nested replaces.  Does this do what you want?

```
UPDATE LOGININFO
    SET DN = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(DN, ',', '\\,'), '\\,OU=', '\,OU='), '\\,DC=', '\,DC=');
```

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Linoff. That really worked. I'm just thinking about one more case where the column value with the escape character \ already available. Executing the scripts which I had posted earlier would also add an additional '\' right? like 'CN=User\\,name,OU=People,DC=domain,DC=com'